# Ffmpeg - How to merge gdigrab and audio with webcam overlay?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to record the screen with webcam overlay, I have the following inputs:

1. Screen capture from gdigrab
2. System Audio using another software that pipes raw audio to ffmpeg
3. Webcam stream
4. Microphone audio

I managed to merge all of the above except for the webcam overlay. here is my ffmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -f f32le -ac 2 -ar 44.1k -i \\.\pipe\systemAudioPipe -f dshow -i video="TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD":audio="Internal Mic (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)" -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 512 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1366x728 -framerate 60 -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a],[a][2:v]overlay" -map 2 -map "[a]" "output.avi"`

and I get this error:

```
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 063ebb80] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_amerge_0' filter output pad 0 (audio) and the 'Parsed_overlay_1' filter input pad 0 (video) [AVFilterGraph @ 063a3a80] Cannot create the link amerge:0 -> overlay:0
```

Error initializing complex filters

if I removed the `[a][2:v]overlay` part from the filter it works fine (without the webcam overlay), so how can I overlay the webcam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[a]` refers to the amerge output, so it can't be sent to a video filter like `overlay`. If you want to overlay the webcam on top of the desktop, `[2:v][1:v]overlay` is the required syntax.

Use

`ffmpeg -f f32le -ac 2 -ar 44.1k -i \\.\pipe\systemAudioPipe -f dshow -i video="TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD":audio="Internal Mic (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)" -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 512 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1366x728 -framerate 60 -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a];[2:v][1:v]overlay[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" "output.avi"`